# No match operator is shown

Tags: c++

Having a problem to print the value in line number 17.Please help me out to solve the problem

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
         int a,b,i;
        cin>>a>>b;
        int count=0;
        for(i=9;i<=b;i*10+9)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

  cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't paraphrase compiler errors, copy them verbatim. 2) Don't tell us to look at line 17 when there are no line numbers. Please mark the offending line with a comment. 3) Is this this your entire code? There are included headers missing.

Comment: 1) cout<<count is the specific line.2) header isn't included.but header is used.

Comment: Your code should present your exact problem. By omitting headers you introduce unrelated problems and send us on a guessing game. Please read what a [mre] is, and [edit] your question appropriately.

Comment: I included header file

Answer (score 1):

The `count` variable you declared within your `while` loop is no longer in scope at the point you attempt to print it.

What *is* in scope is the function [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).  That's why you get an error like

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and '<unresolved overloaded function type>')
```

instead of

```
error: 'count' was not declared in this scope
```

This is yet another reason you shouldn't use `using namespace std`.  Such ambiguity would not have arisen without it.

---

Unrelated to the question you actually asked, the loop

```
for(i=9;i<=b;i*10+9)
```

will never terminate (assuming `b` is greater than 9) since your loop ever actually *modifies* the value of `i`.  It should be

```
for (i = 9; i <= b; i = i * 10 + 9)
//                  ^^^ Assign the result back to i
```

Your compiler should have warned you about this.  For instance, GCC gives the following warning

```
main.cpp:12:26: warning: for increment expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   12 |         for(i=9;i<=b;i*10+9)
```

If it didn't warn you, then you should ensure you are compiling with warnings enabled.

---

Also unrelated, but the header `bits/stdc++.h` is not standard, and should not be used.  `std::cout` is declared in the standard header `iostream`.  Again, if you had used that instead of including the entire standard library you would have been less likely to run into confusing ambiguities.